# How to take a single record in a file and display it vertically with the count of field before the actual field is displayed

Tags: awk, tr

I have a file with a single line in it that has a record that is deliminted by semi-colons.  So far I have figured out that I can use tr by issuing:

```
tr ';' '\n' < t
```

However since the record has 140 fields, I'd like to be able to show the field count when displaying such as the following:

```
1 23
2 324234
3 AAA
.
.
140 Blah
```

Help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just run it through `cat -n`.

```
tr \; '\n' < t | cat -n
```

Since this is tagged `awk`, you could do it that way, too; it's just a little wordier:

```
awk -F\; '{for (i=1;i<=NF;++i) { print i" "$i }}'
```

Answer (score 3):

```
tr \; '\n' <t|nl
```

or

```
awk -v RS=';'  '$1=++i" "$1' file
```

test:

```
kent$  echo "a;b;c;d"|awk -v RS=';'  '$1=++i" "$1'     
1 a
2 b
3 c
4 d
```

Answer (score 1):

In shell you can use `IFS` to specify a field separator like so,

```
IFS=";"
i=0
for s in $(<file)
do
  ((i++)) 
  echo $i $s
done
```